# Guzzle request timed out on localhost

Tags: php, guzzle

I tried to use `GuzzleHttp` on local and make request to local URL but received `Operation timed out`. The code snippet used:

```
    $url = 'https://boot-vue.test'; //local domain, tried with other urls as well
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'verify' => false,
        'timeout' => 5, // Response timeout
        'connect_timeout' => 5, // Connection timeout
        'peer' => false
    ]);
    $response = $client->request($method, $url, [
        'json' => $data,
        'headers' => $headers,
    ]);
```

The above snippet is working for any public website.

Any help is appreciable!

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeouts

Comment: Yes, even after increasing to 300 it's same

Comment: Is there a firewall on the machine, BitNinja in particular? I have encountered serious issues with BitNinja where it randomly blocks Guzzle requests to remote endpoints/local machine endpoints.

Comment: No firewall as far as I know.

Answer (score 8):

Late Answer but for others who face the same problem.

I believe you are using php's development server

php's development server supports only one connection a time

to fix the problem you can either switch to apache (lamp/wamp)

or

run your application in two separate ports (one for api and the actual app)

---

hope helps..

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: In my case, cURL Cli and PHP cURL (plain) working without any error. Only GuzzleHttp Failed. I'm finding solution.